# How does JPA/jHibernate notices external DB changes?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

When I load an entity by id or by query with JPA (in my case Hibernate) - what are the conditions that an external change of the database entry is reflected and the value is not taken from a cache from a previous load?

Is an explicit refresh when loading necessary or can it get automatic notice from the change outside of my application?

Comment: Yes. See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#caching.

Comment: No, you can't. Ralf posted a link about caching. Hibernate's Second Level Cache always works at application level transactions. So external changes wont be noticed if your entities were already cached.